# Zooming lines in d3js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, zooming

I'm just trying to plot a function in javascript by using the d3.js library. I need to add the zoom and pan events. I've done it by following  this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7ec977c95910dd026812

I've drawn some lines on this plane.
My problem is that when I zoom it, the linewidth changes too. 
What I like is that line still having it's original width when zooming. I think I have to redraw it, but I'm not sure if this is the best way.

Can you tellme if there is a better way of doing this, or show me any simple example?.
Thank you!

Comment: See [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957) -- you need what's called semantic zoom.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not supplied any code it is a bit hard to tell. From your description the grid lines you are rendering are being transformed by the zoom matrix.

You can either draw the grid independently of the zoom but you will have to switch between zoomed and grid transforms and will require more code or just re-render the grid lines with the width set to the width times the inverse scale. Eg if your grid lines are two pixels then you can can keep them that width by setting their render width to `2*(1/scale)` which is the same as `2/scale`. Scale being the amount of zoom. The same applies to any objects you wish to keep at a fixed render size.

There is no easy way to avoid re-rendering the gridlines

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#NonScalingStroke

Comment: Browser support might be relevant and it looks bleak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792252/svg-vector-effect-non-scaling-stroke-and-ie